# SSIS - the RPC server is unavailable

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, sql-server-2016

I've installed a instance of SQL Server and i select Integration Services in the setup wizard.

However, when I run SQL Server Management Studio as 'Administrator', I can see my instance under.

- Database Engine
- Analysis Services
- Reporting Services

However, I can't see my instance under 'Integration Services'.

The service is running in Configuration Manager.

**UPDATE 1**

When trying to enter the server name manually it gives the following error:

> the RPC server is unavailable

Comment: did you mean in the login form?

Comment: yes... on login, select Intergration Service.

Comment: i edited the title and the question based on your comments to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

If you means this form:

[image]

For the first time you login you have to enter the integration services server name manually, Note that you don't have to enter the full instance name `Server\Instance`, you just need to enter the `Server` name.

*Example:*

If the machine name is `MyPC` and the SQL server instance is `SQLDATA`, then you should enter `MyPC` not `MyPC\SQLDATA`

**UPDATE**

> the RPC server is unavailable

if you are sure that your account has sufficient privileges you can follow the links provided in the following MSDN answer.

- [The RPC Server is unavailable - Tried almost everything!](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e1e7e568-9116-43de-beb1-6cf3a684582e/the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-tried-almost-everything?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: I've tried that unfortunately it doesn't work. I also selected <Browse for more> 

That then shows your instances... There is nothing under SSIS section.

Comment: @TuckRollworthy make sure that your windows authentication has `sysadmin` role

Comment: @TuckRollworthy also if you enter the machine name, what is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: The RCP Server is unavailible

Comment: thanks for that. I have sys admin and its still not there.

Comment: @TuckRollworthy the link i provided contains helpful informations from persons who have similar issues, check it out

Answer (score 0):

You may need to open port 135 (or whatever port SSIS is running under) in Windows Firewall on the server.

It would be good to specify the executable path (such as E:\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.exe) as well as the specific network type that these connections should come from.