# Getting "The RPC server is unavailable" error while running the SSIS package

Tags: azure, ssis, etl, azure-blob-storage

I have a SSIS package which has Azure Blob Upload Task and Blob connection manager. Whenever I run the package I get:

> The RPC server is unavailable error.

Detail error is as below:

[image]

When I delete the Blob connection manager rest of the package execute successfully.

Task configuration as below:

[image]

Connection manager setting as below:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the task configuration, also showing the related connection setting would be helpful

Comment: Check the following answer it may help: [SSIS - the RPC server is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241221/ssis-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable)

Comment: The link you provided is all about connecting SSIS server from SSMS. However, I checked everything mentioned but still getting same error.

Comment: Try to change `Run64bitRuntime` property [from the project configuration](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/how-to-run-ssis-packages-using-32-bit-drivers-on-a-64-bit-machine)

Comment: In addition, check the following [wiki page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4494.windows-server-troubleshooting-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable.aspx)

Comment: @Hadi Changing Run64bitRuntime property to False worked.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Good Luck +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified `Run64BitRuntime` property to False and it worked!

[image]